# Symfony 3.4 & PHPUnit "Argument 2 must be of type array, null given" during functional test

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, functional-testing, symfony-3.4

I am testing a large web app and have been using PHPUnit for a while to perform functional tests. Testing forms is usually straightforward but recently had an issue I cannot resolve.

Here is the HTML of the route tested:

```
 <html><head></head><body><section class="panel">
Textarea
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="widget-content">
        <form action="/order/order-line/save/2144/0/0" method="POST" novalidate="">                             
          <div class="form-horizontal group-form-display-fix">
            <input type="hidden" id="_productId" name="0[productId]" value="68234">    <div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-4"><label class="required"><span class="required-asterisk" title="This field is required">*</span>
                        Textarea 
    </label></div><div class="col-sm-8 form-input"><div id="_1099" data-groupid="1099"><div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-4"><label for="_1099_textarea" class="">
                    Textarea/ 
    </label></div><div class="col-sm-8 form-input"><textarea id="_1099_textarea" name="0[1099][textarea]" class="textarea">qreqwrwqrqe</textarea></div></div></div></div></div>
                </div>
```

Here is the test in question:

```
public function testTextQuestion() 
{
  $this->client->followRedirects();
  $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/order/order-line/get-view/2144/0/406?_=1526296674384');
  $form = $crawler->selectButton('Save')->form();
  $form['0[1099][textarea]']->setValue('test nonsense');
  $crawler = $this->client->submit($form);
  $this->assertContains('Instruction details updated', $this->client->getResponse()->getContent());
}
```

The test gives an error:

> TypeError: Argument 2 passed to
>   CaseManager\Bundle\OrderBundle\Manager\AnswerManager::buildAndSaveNewAnswers()
>   must be of the type array, null given, called in
>   /software/src/Software/Bundle/OrderBundle/Controller/OrderLineController.php
>   on line 2580

The code in question in the controller is here:

```
$this->get('software_order.answer_manager')->buildAndSaveNewAnswers(
$this->get('software_order_line.repository')->findOr404($orderLineId), $request->get('0'));
```

It looks like instead of getting the '0' a NULL is provided. The POST request is going through fine and when the route is tested manually it all works so I am stumped.

Using Symfony 3.4 and PHPUnit 6.5.8

Comment: can you add the form type or the html generated?

Comment: try to dump your '0' value before calling that function and you will see is it really null  or not : `dump($request->get('0'));die;`

Comment: Just performed the dump and definitely NULL

Comment: Added the HTML.